# correct implementation the Thread with lock screen

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to implement progressbar while my method LlamadoServicio is executed in background.

I need lock screen with my progressDialog and hide this element to complete the process "**LlamadoServicio()**".

[image]

**My method**

```
 progress = ProgressDialog.show(Menu.this, null, null, true);
 progress.setContentView(R.layout.elemento_progress_dialog);

 new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {

   LlamadoServicio("david");

   mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     progress.dismiss();
    }
   });    
  }
 }).start();
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Code looks legit

Comment: instead of `new Thread(new Runnable() ...` need to try [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve ? anyway your code buggy . Its not advisable to use handler inside thread .

Comment: @mpromonet sorry, i published my answers :D

Comment: @DavidHackro: thanks it is more undersandable, even it could be nice to have a little more of explaination

Comment: This could be a nice question, but I can't upvote it until I see a better explanation of the problem. What is your code doing now? What should it be doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use async task for this.

```
private class AsyncTaskSample extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void) {
      LlamadoServicio("david");
  }


  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void) {
       progress.dismiss();
  }


  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   // Things to be done before execution of long running operation. For
   // example showing ProgessDialog
      progress = ProgressDialog.show(Menu.this, null, null, true);
      progress.setContentView(R.layout.elemento_progress_dialog);
      progress.show();
  }

 }
```

Below are few good references about Async Task in android.

http://codetheory.in/android-asynctask/

http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.Vo87yfl97IU

Comment: this code have errors! but it's similiar the correct answer

Comment: @DavidHackro This code solve your question, this should be marked as the final answer

Answer (score 2):

What your code will do is, it will show a progress dialog and will start doing its job by calling `LlamadoServicio("david")`. At the same time, handler will dismiss the progress dialog.

There are two approaches to do this:

1) Use `AsyncTask`, show progress dialog in `onPreExecute()` function, call `LlamadoServicio("david")` in `doInBackground` function and dismiss your progress dialog in `onPostExecute` function.

2) If you still want to use `Thread` and `Handler`, you need to change your code as below:

```
progress = ProgressDialog.show(Menu.this, null, null, true);
 progress.setContentView(R.layout.elemento_progress_dialog);

 new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {

   LlamadoServicio("david");

  }
 }).start();
```

Your **LlamadoServicio** code:

```
void LlamadoServicio(String value) {
// do your job
mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

}
```

Your **Handler** code:

```
    Handler mHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                progress.dismiss();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to lock the screen while your code is running in background, I personally feel you should use async task in this case.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  protected Void doInBackground(Void) {
    /* do your background work */
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void) {
    progress.dismiss();
  }


  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    // Things to be done before execution of long running operation. For
    // example showing ProgessDialog
    progress = ProgressDialog.show(Menu.this, null, null, true);
    progress.setContentView(R.layout.elemento_progress_dialog);
    // use this if you want to lock the screen.
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.show();
  }
}
```

2. The way you are doing it is wrong because in `run()` method you will give call to your service by calling method :

```
LlamadoServicio("david");
```

Lets say your service starts, but this call will not block the handler to post runnable. Hence it will dismiss the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Correct implementation threads

```
private class MyAsyncClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progress = ProgressDialog.show(RegistroAuto.this, null, null, true);
        progress.setContentView(R.layout.elemento_progress_dialog);
        progress.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        autosConsulta = LlamadoServicio(placa);
        if (autosConsulta != null) {
            autosConsulta.setSerie(serie.replaceAll(" ","").trim());
            hp.nuevoAuto(autosConsulta);
            startActivity(new Intent(RegistroAuto.this, PrincipalAutos.class));
            finish();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progress.dismiss();
        finish();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I love spanic/italian coders. Nothing is as good as a mix of english and other language <3